# pass each line in .txt file as argument to python script

Tags: bash, scripting

I have infinite loop in bash, I need to pass each line in my domain.txt file as argument to python script which can only accept one at a time, when it goes through all lines in domain.txt file its gonna move to another task.

Example (first line & second line):

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env python3
while true   #foo
do                        #foo
python3 script.py -d $(sed -n '1p' < domain.txt) && python3 script.py -d $(sed -n '2p' < domain.txt)         #foo
done #foo
```

this way works, however its not optimal at all, If i added third line into my .txt file it would be ignored unless I would edit bash script - I am planning to have around 500-1000 lines

Comment: Why not use python to open the file?

Comment: because I will be using python scripts which are not made by me and are pretty messy.

Comment: Still, then, use a python wrapper instead.

Comment: Do you need to pass each line as a separate argument or run the script once for each line? How does the python script read its input?

Comment: run the script multiple times until it goes through entire .txt list, python script reads it like: 
python3 script.py -domain example.com (where example.com is i want to run through all lines in from my .txt file after thats done its gonna move to another task - running another python script.)

Comment: Yes, but _how_ does it read it. From what you are saying, it sounds like the python script can only accept a sigle argument, but we can't know since you don't tell us what the python script does.

Comment: This python script can only accept one argument, after that it outputs .txt file with results.
So manually I would have to wait until it finishes and run it again with different argument to get other results.
Hence why I want to automatize it so it automatically goes through my entire .txt list with my pre-defined arguments.

Comment: If it can only accept one argument, why are you passing it multiple arguments and expecting it to work? Please [edit] your question and explain these things, we can't guess how your scripts work.

Comment: edited, hopefully you will now understand what I am trying to achieve

Comment: With the new edit, it is clear that my answer cannot help and @terdon's answer will do ;-) Deleted. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your python script can only take one argument at a time, and if you really can't edit it and fix it, then you will have to do something like this:

```bsh
while read -r line; do
    python3 script.py "$line" && python3 foobar.py
done < domain.txt
```

That will iterate over all lines in `domain.txt`, saving each as `$line` which is then passed to your `script.py`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @SecurityQuy you're welcome. But note that this won't speed anything up. Did you maybe want to run the commands in the background? Something like `while read -r line; do ( python3 script.py "$line" && python3 foobar.py ) & done` which will run `script.py` for all lines in parallel.

Comment: Its almost perfect, there is one small problem which is that it does not wait until it goes through all domains.txt lines so after first line it executes the second python script becuase im using && which waits for process to return 0 and goes to execute second task.
If this was fixable also it would be great

Comment: @SecurityQuy again, I don't know what you are doing or how, so I can't guess. If you want to run the `python3 foobar.py` only at the end, then move it to the end! Just do `while read ...; done < domain.txt && python3 foobar.py`. If you need more details, please post a new question but make sur you actually explain what you need.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! However when using your bash script it does not loop anymore

Comment: figured it out... simply executed sh ./script.sh at end of script - thanks for all your help.

Comment: after domain.txt finishes how would I make same conditions for another python script with different text file? Trying to figure this out but nothing worked yet.

Comment: @SecurityQuy as I told you before, please ask a new question where you can explain what you need.

Comment: question published :)